# How to configure webpack to load css that imports css files?

Tags: webpack

I use webpack to load a css files from the node module *onsenui*:

```
require('onsenui/css/onsenui.css');
require('onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css');
```

The file *onsenui/css/onsenui.css* does import relative css files:

```
@import url("font_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css");
@import url("material-design-iconic-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css");
```

With a webpack configuration as follows:

```
module: {
 loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: [ 'babel' ],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: __dirname
  },
  {
    test: /\.css?$/,
    loaders: [ 'style', 'css'],
    include: __dirname
  }
 ]
}
```

But I get the following errors in my browser:

```
http://localhost:9001/font_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9001/material-design-iconic-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9001/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Does the *css-loader* not handle the `@import` statements? How should I solve the loading of the `@import url(...)` stagements? I can'r rewrite css files from node_modules...

Answer (score 3):

Solved: *css-loader* does handle `@import url(...)` statements, I overlooked that there were multiple `webpack.config.js` files...

I now got another issue with the loading of fonts, had to add an additional rule:

```
loaders: [
  {
      test: /\.css?$/,
      loaders: [ 'style', 'css' ],
  },
  {
      test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
      loader : 'file-loader'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while webpacking onsenui's css... To fix it, I had to tell webpack to load fonts through file-loader, as [Serge van den Oever answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37219820/345422), but in a new way as provided by [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-css/) at the time of this answer.

Besides, I had to remove 'style-loader' from loaders list for css, as [explained here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/503#issuecomment-302228734).

Below, my final webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [ /*'style-loader',*/ 'css-loader' ]
      })
    },{
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
      use: [ 'file-loader' ]
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
  ]
};
```

Thus, bundle.js, style.css, and a lot of fonts files were created within lib directory.

HTH